How can unidimensional lines belong to $B(R^2)$?
It is well known that the Borel sets $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ can be generated by sets of the form $A_1 \times A_2$, where $A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then it seems clear that any set $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ can be written as countable unions, intersections and complements of sets of the form $A_1 \times A_2$, but apparently that is not true.
If we take the line $y = x$ in the plane, the line belong to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ but cannot be written in terms of rectangles $A_1 \times A_2$. What am I missing? Does it mean that lines do not belong to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

What you are missing is that the word "generated" does not mean what you think it does when dealing with σ-algebras. Speaking loosely, you have to take intersections of unions of intersection of unions of intersections of etc. etc. etc. .... an infinite number of times before things "stabilize". You can read the Wikipedia article on Generating the Borel sets for more details.
But your diagonal is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, and we can show it quite explicitly. First let
$$D_n =\bigcup_{r \in \mathbb Q} (r-\frac{1}{n},r+\frac{1}{n})\times (r-\frac{1}{n},r+\frac{1}{n}),$$
which is a countable union of sets of the form $A_1 \times A_2$. and is kind of a thin jagged band along the diagonal. And then
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n$$
takes the width of the band to zero, which leaves just the diagonal line.

Thank you! Indeed that's a way to write the diagonal line. This argument should generalize easily for bigger dimensions, right?

Yup. Just write it as $(r-\frac{1}{n},r+\frac{1}{n})^n$ for the n-fold product of intervals.
